# How to write a get method DynamoDB with global secondary index?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify, amplifyjs

I'm new to dynamoDB and NoSQL in general. I used aws amplify to create this table:

```
{
    "Table": {
        "AttributeDefinitions": [
            {
                "AttributeName": "category",
                "AttributeType": "S"
            },
            {
                "AttributeName": "id",
                "AttributeType": "S"
            },
            {
                "AttributeName": "title",
                "AttributeType": "S"
            }
        ],
        "TableName": "products2-prod",
        "KeySchema": [
            {
                "AttributeName": "category",
                "KeyType": "HASH"
            },
            {
                "AttributeName": "title",
                "KeyType": "RANGE"
            }
        ],
        "TableStatus": "ACTIVE",
        "CreationDateTime": 1574728653.881,
        "ProvisionedThroughput": {
            "NumberOfDecreasesToday": 0,
            "ReadCapacityUnits": 5,
            "WriteCapacityUnits": 5
        },
        "TableSizeBytes": 0,
        "ItemCount": 0,
        "TableArn": "arn:aws:dynamodb:xxxxx:table/products2-prod",
        "TableId": "7c3ae2a1-cef1-4e52-85e5-b8ef543b0d30",
        "GlobalSecondaryIndexes": [
            {
                "IndexName": "byId",
                "KeySchema": [
                    {
                        "AttributeName": "id",
                        "KeyType": "HASH"
                    }
                ],
                "Projection": {
                    "ProjectionType": "ALL"
                },
                "IndexStatus": "ACTIVE",
                "ProvisionedThroughput": {
                    "NumberOfDecreasesToday": 0,
                    "ReadCapacityUnits": 5,
                    "WriteCapacityUnits": 5
                },
                "IndexSizeBytes": 0,
                "ItemCount": 0,
                "IndexArn": "arn:aws:dynamodb:xxxxx:table/products2-prod/index/byId"
            },
            {
                "IndexName": "byTitle",
                "KeySchema": [
                    {
                        "AttributeName": "title",
                        "KeyType": "HASH"
                    }
                ],
                "Projection": {
                    "ProjectionType": "ALL"
                },
                "IndexStatus": "ACTIVE",
                "ProvisionedThroughput": {
                    "NumberOfDecreasesToday": 0,
                    "ReadCapacityUnits": 5,
                    "WriteCapacityUnits": 5
                },
                "IndexSizeBytes": 0,
                "ItemCount": 0,
                "IndexArn": "arn:aws:dynamodb:xxxxx:table/products2-prod/index/byTitle"
            }
        ],
        "StreamSpecification": {
            "StreamEnabled": true,
            "StreamViewType": "NEW_IMAGE"
        },
        "LatestStreamLabel": "2019-11-26T00:37:33.881",
        "LatestStreamArn": "arn:aws:dynamodb:xxxxx:table/products2-prod/stream/2019-11-26T00:37:33.881"
    }
}
```

I want to be able to get an item only by its title, so I added this to my app.js file:

```
app.get(path + '/name'  + '/:title', function(req, res) {
  let params = {}
  try {
    params["title"] = convertUrlType(req.params["title"], "S");
  } catch (err) {
    res.json({ error: 'Wrong column type ' + err });
  }

  let getItemParams = {
    TableName: tableName,
    IndexName: "byTitle",
    Key: params
  }

  dynamodb.get(getItemParams,(err, data) => {
    if(err) {
      res.statusCode = 500;
      res.json({error: 'Could not load items: ' + err.message});
    } else {
      if (data.Item) {
        res.json(data.Item);
      } else {
        res.json(data) ;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

But, I get this error when I try to get an item using the byTitle GSI:

{"error":"Could not load items: The provided key element does not match the schema"}

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

In the documentation I don't see that IndexName is an option for [get](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#get-property) operation. Try to use [query](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#query-property) instead.

Comment: That's right.. A GSI is a projection of records in the original table. In the table, the PK + SK ensure that you can retrieve a single entry, which is what 'get' does. On the other hand, the GSI's partition key does not ensure record uniqueness since multiple records on the main table could have the same value in a property used as the PK for your GSI. Because of this, scan and query are the only operations permitted on a GSI